# Make PopUp completely intransparent

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I use the popup to implement a kind of "autocomplete-list" with data from user-input.

The problem is: The popup is as little bit transparent and you can see the elements behind the list.
I want a list that is complete intransparent.
No "Opacity" is set, not to the popup, nor to the list (the element in the popup).

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Please include a minimal xaml/code sample which demonstrates the problem you are seeing.

Comment: What happens if you set the `Opacity` to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Popup control on its own is transparent. You will generally put a container inside it to host and layout the contents. This container should have a theme-appropriate background. Depending on your design that may be completely opaque or it may be partially transparent.

Here's an opaque snippet. You'll probably want to choose a different colour in production :)

```
<Popup x:Name="mypop">
    <Grid Background="Magenta">
        <TextBlock Width="600" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"/>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```